# Why Shopify ecommerce website uses react to build the store?

Tags: reactjs, shopify

I am new to React language. I have been working in the Shopify store for a year. Now they updated their store to React. if React is for the single page web/application then Why Shopify Implemented it? I Really need to understand this.

Comment: Why do you think React application is only for Single Page Application?

Comment: @Bhojendra I have checked in the React Js websitec [link]https://monosnap.com/file/Xc10gnMePXz61O3TnOL0bgHmaBD04k [link]https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#gatsby                                                                                              I already mentioned that I am new to reactJs. I really wanted to learn in a good way. Thats why asked for the question. Answer to this may help some person with the same doubt. Instead of Helping Why You people down voting the question??

Answer (score 1):

No assets from Shopify are ReactJS save for Polaris, used for creating EASDK Apps. There is no obligation to use this Polaris library. This question is not really accurate. No store in Shopify has to use React, but an EASDK custom App could, if you choose to use the Polaris ReactJS library. No obligation to do so.

Short Answer: No (few) Shopify commerce websites use React to build their shops. They use Liquid, HTML, CSS and JS yes, but not React as that is not really appropriate for shops themselves.

Comment: thank you very much for clarifying the doubt @David. I work in liquid and HTML CSS and JS in the store theme. Yes as you mentioned it uses Polaris library. in theme we use html css and JS.